# Encountering some weird layer gaps on the last few lines of a particular print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, filament-quality, layer-shifting

I'm working on printing the [3D Printable Jet Engine w/ Minimal Printing Supports](https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/various/3d-printable-jet-engine-minimal-printing-supports) and I'm having a surprising amount of difficulty printing the fan. The fan seems to print fine, right up until the last 20 or so layers, where it starts to gap and blob-like I've never seen before.

I have quite a few photos [available to view](https://imgur.com/a/9Cgmu9F), but I'm including a few below:

[image: Photo of jet engine fan model with gaps and blobs]

[image: Upclose photo of the same fan model]

Settings/components:

- Ender 3 S1 Pro (running Klipper)
- Filaments tried: [SUNLU 3D Printer Silk PLA Filament 1.75 mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B5Z221QB) and [AMOLEN Shiny Silk Black PLA Filament 1.75 mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C69HXGWW)
- Nozzle size: .4 mm
- Layer heights: 0.16 mm, 0.2 mm
- Speeds: 100 mm/s, 75 mm/s
- Temperature: 205 °C, 210 °C, 215 °C
- Retraction: Yes, tuned with with retraction towers
- Slicer: Cura

What I have tried:

- Initially, I thought that maybe it was because I had the infill set to ~40 %, and a lot of top layers, so maybe the print geometry and the infill/top layers combo caused it, but they showed up when I put the infill to 100 %, as well as if I just put the walls to 20 (thus making it 100 %).
- I've tried printing with .20 mm and .16 mm layer height, as well as .16 mm + adaptive layers (which made a lot of it .12 mm)
- Tried switching to a different filament, and encountered the same results.
- Printed some tuning towers to verify that the temperature and retraction are set up okay.
- Tried lowering the speed down to 75 mm/s (usually around 100 mm/s)

If it was something like a clogged nozzle, then I would assume that that same pattern would be seen everywhere on the print. That goes for the temperature and retraction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-printed the model using Curas overlay settings and some stretched cubes to apply different settings to some of the fan blades:
[image]
And once printed, the blade seen here at the very bottom looks like it was the best:
[image]
The changes on that blade were just 4 bottom layers, 0 top layers and 7 walls (effectively making everything after the bottom 4 layers 100% density with just walls).

I'm not sure why exactly the gap between the top layers and the walls was showing up, but regardless, this seems to be the fix.